# Spacy Rule Based Matching entities are overwriting existing entities, How to preserve

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm using Spacy 1.8.2. I have added some custom entities:

```
def add_entity(matcher, document, i, matches):
        ent_id, label, start, end = matches[i]      
        document.ents += (Span(document, start, end, label),)   

nlp.matcher.add_entity("person_one",on_match=add_entity)  
nlp.matcher.add_pattern("person_one",[{ENT_TYPE:"PERSON"}],label = "PERSON_ONE")
```

Now, **PERSON_ONE** entities are **identified**, but **PERSON entity is not**.

I want all default entities as well as custom entities for any span which matches any custom rule.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like spaCy doesn't support overlapping entities; see [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/242)

> The problem is that the Matcher class automatically sets named entity annotations, but the named entity annotations don't allow overlapping entities. The lack of overlapping entities is not ideal, but it's a standard limitation, and not so problematic.

As mentioned, this is a pretty standard limitation of NER systems.

A very simple way to work around this is to run NER twice, once with your rule and once without, and merge the entities.